# Basic operation giving different results in Python

Tags: python

I was playing around with few basic operations in Python 3 and came across this

**Code 1:**

```
a = 6
b = 3
a = a / 2 * b
print(a)
```

Output is `9.0`

In one of the trainings I have seen that

```
a = a / 2
```

can be written as

```
a /= 2
```

So I re-wrote my above code as below

**Code 2:**

```
a = 6
b = 3
a /= 2 * b
print(a)
```

But now the output is `1.0`.
I was expecting 9.0 as output. Can someone help me understand why code behaves this way?

Comment: this is about the precedence of the operations... the first is `(a / 2) * b`; the second `a / (2 * b)`.

Comment: there are no brackets involved here..will python assume there is bracket when i don't have one?

Comment: python makes a (documented [left-to-right]) choice. it has to. you seem to imagine parentheses here as well... just not around the same operations.

Comment: added an answer; my reply was too long for a comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python operator precedence with augmented assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52505021/python-operator-precedence-with-augmented-assignment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of `a /= 2 * b`, you saying that `a` will be divided by expression after `/=`.

In other words, your expression could be rewritten as `a = a / (2 * b)` where `a = 6, b = 3`

Comment: ok..got it..but in that case it will be wrong to say
a = a / 2 and 
a /= 2 are always equivalent, right?

Answer (score 0):

in

```
a /= 2 * b
```

the 2 * b is carried out first so if b == 3 it can be rewritten as:

```
a /= 6
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because they perform operations in different order.

The first of block of code divides a (6) by 2 and then multiplies that result by b (3)

E.g. (6 / 2) * 3 = 9

However the second block of code does the following:

6 / (2 * 3) = 1

Answer (score 0):

**Note, that**

```
a /= 2 * b
```

is basically

```
a = a / (2 * b)
```

The previous code is different. It's not like the above (look at the parentheses)

```
a = a / 2 * b
```

This is different than

```
a = a / (2 * b)
```

Because the first code interpret it as division and then multiply, while the second code interpret it as multiply (bottom) and then division.

Comment: does it mean, even if I don't explicitly mention a bracket, python will take it that way in second case?

Comment: @AbrahamPanicker Every language does that. It's not about python, but the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

as you can see in the [documentatiopn on operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) `*` and `/` have the same precedence. two operations with the same precedence are executed from left to right:

> Operators in the same box group left to right

so your first example is evaluated as

```
(a / 2) * b
```

the second as

```
a / (2 * b)
```

regarding your comment

> `a = a / 2` and `a /= 2` are always equivalent, right?

for the built-in python numbers you are right.

for your own classes you can make the operations differ. if `a` is an insance of a custom class `a/x` will call `__truediv__(self, other)` while `a/=x` will call `__itruediv__(self, other)` as described in the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

Comment: yes..I got the logic behind getting a different value, but then my question becomes how can we say that 
a = a / 2 and a /= 2 are always equivalent.
This purely depends on whether there is further expressions after first expression

Comment: do you have an example for what you mean? in the `/=` case everything on the right-hand-side will be calculated before the division (and the assignment).

Comment: yes...you can add any further ops to that right side and its all considered as part of that same bracket and gets evaluated before division
eg. a /= 2 * b + a
is equivalent to a = a / (2 * b + a)

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised none of the other answers mention this, but the reason doesn't have anything to do with math, order of operations or implicit parentheses.

`x /= y` is just another way of saying `x.__itruediv__(y)`. Your second example is not equivalent to your first example, because parameters are evaluated before being passed in to a function call. So, `a /= 2 * b` is equivalent to `a.__itruediv__(2 * b)`, and naturally, the expression `2 * b` must be evaluated before being passed in to `__itruediv__`.

Comment: Hiro mentioned it in previous comment and gave the link to data model documentation of python :)